# .NET based Desktop open source booking application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, desktop-application

Anybody know of an existing open-source booking systems in Sports Clubs or Leisure Facilities based on .NET?

I searched Google, but nothing relevant came up!

Comment: Booking what? Hotel rooms, event tickets, illegally parked cars?

Comment: -1..For not just a bad question but also bad googling !

Comment: is this for a school project??. if so, i reckon you'll be 'rumbled' :-).. !!!

Comment: @amir - Just a word of warning.  If you use an existing project for a homework assignment you will recieve a failing grade.  If you are actually working on this for a job be sure not to take credit for the word, because if in the future there is a problem and you do take credit, you will run into some problems.

Comment: sorry, Booking in a leisure system or sports clubs!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, in VB, no less:
[Box Office](http://boxoffice.codeplex.com/).

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat open source.... [Simpletix.com](http://www.simpletix.com/Features/) gives you complete control over the CSS. It's built on C# and Asp.net.
 There's a million EventBrite type sites. But this is the only one that is download-able. The fact that you download it gives you access to the asp.net files.